# Cannot compile R package with Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, devtools, r-package

I'm trying to build a R package and I'm using Rcpp in one of my functions. I can load the function with sourceCpp("~/Desktop/trial/src/code.cpp") and I don't have any issues using the function on it's own, but I get errors when trying to add it and build the package. When I run devtools::load_all() I get the following error,

```
  System command 'R' failed, exit status: 1, stdout + stderr (last 10 lines):
E>     Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< string >::type delim(delimSEXP);
E>                                    ^~~~~~
E>                                    String
E> /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/String.h:49:11: note: 'String' declared here
E>     class String {
E>           ^
E> 12 errors generated.
E> make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 1
E> ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘trial’
E> * removing ‘/private/var/folders/52/y1qz8q711pd8cv60r_687c6m0000gn/T/RtmpOO3W0e/devtools_install_aae030821fbc/trial’
```

The C++ code I'm using can be found at https://wckdouglas.github.io/2015/05/string-manipulation . To build the package I ran

```
devtools::create("trial")
setwd("~/trial")
usethis::use_rcpp() #At this point I added the cpp file to the src directory
Rcpp::compileAttributes()
devtools::load_all()
```

Is there something in the cpp code that conflicts with adding it to a R package? Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: You are not showing a [minimally complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so it is difficult to say anything definitive---but if I had to guess I would suspect that you package structure is just wrong.  Maybe look at what `Rcpp.package.skeleton("testPackage")` builds, vereify that it builds (it will !!) and compare to what you have.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The C++ code that I'm using can be found at https://wckdouglas.github.io/2015/05/string-manipulation. I tried building a package with just the cpp file and was unsuccessful. To build the package I ran `devtools::create("trial") ` , `setwd("~/trial")` , `usethis::use_rcpp()` , then I copied the code from the link into a cpp file in the src folder, then ran `Rcpp::compileAttributes()` and `devtools::load_all` . It's at this step that I run into an error. What do I need to do to correct the package structure?

Comment: Well I already mentioned using `Rcpp.package.skeleton()` in my previous comment. Alternatively there is also a 'Package with Rcpp' generator in RStudio.  None of the official Rcpp documentation suggests `usethis` or `devtools`, and I don't use those packages myself. So if you have trouble with those packages but want to use them it might be best to contact _their_ authors instead.

Answer (score 1):

I get different errors when using `gcc` on Linux. But most importantly, the first error reported by the compiler is telling:

```
   RcppExports.cpp:9:1: error: ‘stringList’ does not name a type
       9 | stringList string_split(stringList x, string sep, int start, int frag);
         | ^~~~~~~~~~
```

Now this does make sense, since `stringList` is a `typedef` in the original code that does not automatically propagate to `RcppExports.cpp`. The solution can be found in section 2.5 of the Rcpp Attributes vignette: Create a file `src/trial_types.h` (there are other possbile names and places, see the docs):

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef vector<string> stringList;
typedef vector<int> numList;
```

And replace the `typedef`s in the C++ code with `#include "trial_types.h"`.

BTW, in package code I would not use `using namespace std;` and `using namespace Rcpp;`.